# How to run c8 with typesrcipt, and jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, code-coverage

I have a node typescript app, and using jest for testing. I have tried to use `c8` to check my code coverage in the tests. The documentation doesn't say anything special about setup, so I was running:

```
c8 --check-coverage jest --maxWorkers 4
```

It's returning:

```
A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.

Test Suites: 25 passed, 25 total
Tests:       104 passed, 104 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        58.206 s, estimated 62 s
Ran all test suites.
✨  Done in 59.37s.
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Note the first line which says a worker process has failed to exit gracefully. If I'm running the tests without c8, it doesn't appear, so might be related to the issue.

I'm not sure what's going wrong, and haven't even found anyone facing the same issue. What can be the problem in this case?

Comment: Two indirect solution ideas. 1. I see people use `c8 npm run unittest` pattern, they don't chain `c8` onto test runner itself but rather onto `npm run`. Try that. My open source projects use `c8` and `uvu` and tests are in `js` and it works; npm script is `"devtest": "c8 yarn run unit"` and `"unit": "uvu test"`. 2. If anything, Jest on TS will be slow; there are more performant tools, for example, Remix has Vitest wired up by default and allegedly its API is interchangeable with Jest's.